# How can I check which terminal definitions are available?

Tags: linux, terminal, solaris, console, ncurses

The bulk of the question is in title, but to elaborate a little:

On most Linuxes I can `find /usr/share/terminfo -type f`. But on Solaris machine I have nearby - this directory doesn't even exist.

I could iterate over a list of terminals, and do something like:

```
for TERM in xterm xtermc xterm-color xterm-256color screen rxvt
do
    tput cols >/dev/null 2>/dev/null && echo "$TERM available"
done
```

But it's slow. Any options to discover path used by `tput` to terminal definitions, and run "find" myself?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On Solaris 10 you can do:

```
find /usr/share/lib/terminfo -type f -print
```

You should be able to do something like:

```
find /usr -type d -name terminfo -print
```

to find where the directory is located.

You can also read to find the exact path:

```
man terminfo
```

Comment: This is great, but I have one small problem with it - how can I find the path, without grepping man output? It there any way to do it?

Comment: I've amended the answer.

Answer (score 21):

The infocmp program on "any" system supporting terminfo happens to show the pathname where it finds the terminal description for the current terminal.  For example (AIX in this case):

```
$ infocmp vt100
#       Reconstructed via infocmp from file: /usr/share/lib/terminfo/v/vt100
vt100|vt100-am|Digital VT100,
        am, msgr, xenl, xon,
        cols#80, it#8, lines#24, vt#3,
        ...
```

For ncurses, it is more complicated, because you can have multiple terminfo databases, and the entries need not be individual files.  A single database and one file per entry is the *default*, for compatibility with Unix systems.

The `-D` option for [tic](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tic.1m.html) and [infocmp](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/infocmp.1m.html) (added [late in 2011](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/NEWS.html#t20111126)) is one way to show the extra information.  For example, on my Debian7, I can see this:

```
$ infocmp6 -D
/users/tom/.terminfo
/usr/local/ncurses/share/terminfo
/usr/share/terminfo
/lib/terminfo
```

On my FreeBSD 10 machine, I use hashed databases:

```
$ infocmp -D
/usr/local/ncurses/share/terminfo.db
/usr/local/share/misc/terminfo
/etc/termcap
```

Alternatively, one can use the [`toe`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/toe.1m.html) program to produce a report of all of the available terminal entries.  Using the `-s` and `-a` options lets it combine things (like the [`conflict`](http://invisible-island.net/conflict/conflict.html) program):

```
--> /users/tom/.terminfo
----> /usr/local/ncurses/share/terminfo
------> /usr/share/terminfo
--------> /lib/terminfo
--*-+---:       9term           Plan9 terminal emulator for X
--*---*-:       Eterm           Eterm with xterm-style color support (X Window System)
--*-*---:       Eterm-256color  Eterm with xterm 256-colors
--*-*---:       Eterm-88color   Eterm with 88 colors
--*-+---:       MtxOrb          Generic Matrix Orbital LCD display
--*-+---:       MtxOrb162       16x2 Matrix Orbital LCD display
--*-+---:       MtxOrb204       20x4 Matrix Orbital LCD display
--*-+---:       NCR260VT300WPP  NCR 2900_260 vt300 wide mode pc+  kybd
--*-+---:       aaa             ann arbor ambassador/30 lines
--*-+---:       aaa+dec         ann arbor ambassador in dec vt100 mode
--*-+---:       aaa+rv          ann arbor ambassador in reverse video
...
```

Answer (score 1):

On Linux you can use `strace` to see which system calls a program uses. The following will list all "open(2)" system calls and filter them through `sed` to show, hopefully, the terminfo file used by `tput` to translate the terminfo capability for the current terminal.

```
TERMINFO_FILE=$(strace -e open tput cud1 2>&1 | sed -n -e 's/^.*\(".*terminfo.*"\).*$/\1/p')
echo ${TERMINFO_FILE}
```

Note that that sed expression assumes that your terminfo files are stored in a path with the pattern "terminfo" in it. If that worries you then you could use a different assumption and pick the last "open" system call.

```
TERMINFO_FILE=$(strace -e open tput cud1 2>&1 | grep -e "^open" | tail -n 1 | sed -n -e 's/^.*\(".*"\).*$/\1/p')
echo ${TERMINFO_FILE}
```

Finally, you can just dump the list of terminfo search paths using `infocmp -D` or `tic -D`. These will list their compiled-in terminfo search paths. These are the same paths searched by curses.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue an a Zyxel NSA310

the solution that worked for me was

```
export TERM=xterm
```

advice was given here:

https://better-coding.com/solved-xterm-256color-unknown-terminal-type/